# Default to ActiveSync for Exchange Calendar

Tags: calendar

Even though I have Exchange ActiveSync set up in my iPhone 6 settings, when I create a new appointment it defaults to iPhone calendar instead. How do I set the ActiveSync calendar as the default?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a default calendar in **Settings** → **Mail, Contacts & Calendars** → **Default Calendar** (right at the bottom).